# Ruby on Rails - Query Multiple Models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I created a ActiveRecord model that does not have a corresponding table in the database. I want it to manage the application 'scoped' queries:

```
class Meter <ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.daily_tests
    self.connection.execute(sanitize_sql(["SELECT b.*, m.*, i.* FROM bgtests AS b JOIN meals AS m ON b.user_id = m.user_id JOIN injections AS i ON i.user_id = m.user_id WHERE b.user_id = 2 AND m.user_id = 2 AND i.user_id = 2"]))
  end
end
```

The query executes however the result set brings back this:

```
{"id"=>1, "value"=>712, "category"=>"basal", "time_of_day"=>"Before dinner", "comments"=>"Est et aut. Est maxime sunt. Dolor doloribus distinctio sed reprehenderit culpa. Autem ipsam atque modi dolor ut non. Aut dicta voluptate occaecati.", "user_id"=>2, "created_at"=>"2015-06-21 18:58:55.806367", "updated_at"=>"2015-06-21 18:58:55.806367", "name"=>"snack", "carbohydrates"=>142, "description"=>"Facere reiciendis non officia velit consequatur voluptas eum. Veritatis quia cumque. Dolor non eaque quod. Dignissimos quae aut eveniet sunt ea amet. Iste et aut unde consequatur quia commodi.", "num_of_units_taken"=>1.0, 0=>10, 1=>712, 2=>"smbg", 3=>"Before dinner", 4=>"Est et aut. Est maxime sunt. Dolor doloribus distinctio sed reprehenderit culpa. Autem ipsam atque modi dolor ut non. Aut dicta voluptate occaecati.", 5=>2, 6=>"2015-06-21 18:58:55.595625", 7=>"2015-06-21 18:58:55.595625", 8=>12, 9=>"snack", 10=>142, 11=>"Facere reiciendis non officia velit consequatur voluptas eum. Veritatis quia cumque. Dolor non eaque quod. Dignissimos quae aut eveniet sunt ea amet. Iste et aut unde consequatur quia commodi.", 12=>2, 13=>"2015-06-21 18:58:56.115615", 14=>"2015-06-21 18:58:56.115615", 15=>1, 16=>1.0, 17=>"basal", 18=>2, 19=>"2015-06-21 18:58:55.806367", 20=>"2015-06-21 18:58:55.806367"},
```

The initial key-values are return as column-value however it then switches and adds subsequent records as 5=>2 for example.

My question is how can I query these multiple models on the foreign_key 'user_id" and have the result set bring back all the results in the typical object notation specific to the model?

Comment: Can you tag with what db are you using? Also, why do you want to query in this way? You can write this query in AR...

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with Rails 4.1 + PostgreSQL. Do you have columns with the same name on different tables?

Comment: I'd prefer to use AR. I do have a user_id column in each of the three tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the methods defined by the [ActiveRecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) accept SQL string arguments in addition to other forms specified in the docs. You can also arbitrarily chain these methods, and AR will combine to create a proper SQL. When in doubt, use `to_sql` to view the SQL generated. Assuming `bgtests` corresponds to a model called `Bgtest`, you could for example do the following:

```
Bgtest.select("b.*, m.*, i.*").from("bgtests b")
.joins("JOIN meals AS m ON b.user_id = m.user_id")
.joins("JOIN injections AS i ON i.user_id = m.user_id")
.where("b.user_id = 2 AND m.user_id = 2 AND i.user_id = 2")
```

Method chaining works this way because each method returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object that accepts the same [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) methods as ActiveRecord::Base (which your models subclass). Ordering of the method calls is therefore arbitrary. The SQL is not actually executed until you attempt to extract a value from the relation, whether due to the console calling `to_s` or because you call `each` in a view.

Note that the above can be greatly simplified (and much more "Rails-y") by defining the correct [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on the models. In particular, the classes `Bgtest`, `Meal`, and `Injection` would all apparently call `belongs_to :user`, and `User` would call `has_many :bgtests`, etc. You can then use [`has_many` with `:through` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) in other classes, e.g. `Bgtest` could call `has_many :meals, through: user`, etc. AR would then know to `INNER JOIN` based on referencing the association names alone:

```
Bgtest.joins(:meals, :injections).where(user_id: 2)
```

or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
Bgtest.includes(:meals, :injections).where(user_id: 2)
```